# Change the jQueryUI tab caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a very simple jQueryui tab set up

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1"><p>Container 1</p></div>
  <div id="tabs-2"><p>Container 2</p></div>
  <div id="tabs-3"><p>Container 3</p></div>
</div>
```

I feel really dumb because I can't Google an answer but all I want to do is to change the tabs label/caption/text.

So Tab 1 becomes "Employee 12345" or "John Smith" such as:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">John Smith</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Mary Doe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Mickey Mouse</a></li>
</ul>
```

All using code such as jquery or javascript

Do I need to build the entire section with an HTML string and then repopulate the parent div?  or can I select the element and change a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling the tab titles from a Database, you will need to get that data first. I would suggest storing it in an Array.

Once you have the array, you can replace the HTML text before calling Tabs.

```js
$(function() {
  // Create AJAX call to populate names
  // Example Data for Example
  var names = [
    "John Smith",
    "Mary Doe",
    "Mickey Mouse"
  ];
  $("#tabs ul li a").each(function(ind, el) {
    $(el).html(names[ind]);
  });
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1 title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2 title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3 title</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Tab 1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Tab 2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Tab 3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will want to make an AJAX call and store the values in an array or assign the values in `success` callback. Your choice. We then just update the Inner HTML of the Hyper Links.

In the future, it is best to include all the details of what you are trying to accomplish.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this :)

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1 title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2 title</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3 title</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Tab 1 content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Tab 2 content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Tab 3 content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to change it from a javascript function.  I need to read data from a database and put the employees name on the tab using an Ajax call that is in a javascript function.